# Means for compiling C# run-time code into a .dll in native assembly code (callable from a C++ application)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

My friend and I have put together a C# run-time library which we want to compile, or convert, into a .dll in native assembly code and call from a C++ application.

I suspected we might not be the first ones embarking on this type of an effort. So I looked around and came up with the following:

1. [How to migrate from C++ COM to C++CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265835/how-to-migrate-from-c-com-to-ccli)
2. [Managed C++ wrappers for legacy C++ libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425752/managed-c-wrappers-for-legacy-c-libraries/425919#425919)
3. [Writing a managed wrapper for unmanaged (C++) code - custom types/structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941100/writing-a-managed-wrapper-for-unmanaged-c-code-custom-types-structs/2941139#2941139)
4. [how to convert C# to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651249/how-to-convert-c-sharp-to-c)
5. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268197-convert-c-form-c-net

However, these links all talk about how to port C++ code to CLI or C#. There is no mention of how to port C# managed code to a standalone .dll library in native assembly callable from a C++ application.

Any thoughts?

Best regards,

Baldur

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need an *unmanaged* wrapper around a *managed* library, which is the opposite of the more common problem.

The basic idea is to create a C++ library that has unmanaged exports (native C-style functions) but internally used managed C++ to interact with your library.

Be aware that marshalling unmanaged *data* across layers may be tricky - hopefully you only need to use very basic types (strings and numbers).

Also note that the client will *still* need to have the appropriate .NET framework installed - wrapping the library will not get around that requirement.

Here's a few links that may help:

[Calling a C# function from unmanaged C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780368/calling-a-c-sharp-function-from-unmanaged-c-via-a-managed-wrapper)

[Using managed code in an unmanaged application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword for your problem COM Component in C++ look the example below:

You can regsiter your .Net assembly with COM after that you can call it from C++.

See the example below:

```
[Guid(123565C4-C5FA-4512-A560-1D47F9FDFA20")]
public interface ISomeInteface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    string FirstFunction{ get; }

    [DispId(2)]
    void SecondFunction();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(123565C4-C5FA-4512-A560-1D47F9FDFA20")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public sealed class SomeInteface: ISomeInteface
{
    public SomeInteface()
    {
    }

   public string FirstFunction
   {
    get { return "Work here"; }
   }

    public void SecondFunction()
   {
   }
}
```

More info;You can take a look in the following links: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/440aca96-288a-4d5c-ab9a-87ea2cdd5ca8/how-to-call-c-dll-from-c
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736